# Conditionally move MySQL data between rows in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, redmine

Working in Redmine, I need to copy(not move) data from certain rows to other rows based on matching project id numbers with time entries.

I have included a diagram of the table "custom_values" and my understanding of the design below(CURRENT DATA):

```
+----+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+-------+
| id | customized_type | customized_id | custom_field_id | value |
+----+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+-------+
| 1  | Project         |             1 |               1 | 01    |
| 2  | TimeEntry       |             1 |               4 | 01    |
| 3  | Project         |             2 |               1 | 02    |
| 4  | TimeEntry       |             2 |               4 | 02    |
| 5  | Project         |             3 |               1 | 03    |
| 6  | TimeEntry       |             3 |               4 |       |
| 7  | Project         |             4 |               1 | 04    |
| 8  | TimeEntry       |             4 |               4 |       |
+----+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+-------+
```

At the risk of oversimplifying,

- "id" = The primary key for each entry in custom_values
- "customized_type" = Specifies which db table the row is referring to.
- "customized_id" = Specifies the primary key for the db table entry previously specified in "customized_type".
- "custom_field_id" = Specifies which custom field the row is referring to.  Redmine admins can arbitrarily add and remove custom fields.
- "value" = The data contained within the custom field specified by
  "custom_field_id"

In my situation, the values listed in "value" are representing unique customer id numbers.  The customer id numbers did not always get entered with each time entry.  I need to copy the customer numbers from the project rows to the matching time entry rows.  Each time entry has a project_id field.

So far, here is my mangled SQL query:

```
SELECT 
custom_field_id,
custom_values.value AS 'CUSTOMER_NUMBER', 
custom_values.customized_id AS 'PROJECT_ID_NUMBER', 
custom_values.customized_type,
time_entries.comments AS 'TIME_ENTRY_COMMENTS'
FROM
redmine_tweaking.custom_values
LEFT JOIN
redmine_tweaking.time_entries ON custom_values.customized_id = time_entries.project_id
WHERE 
custom_values.customized_type='Project' AND custom_values.custom_field_id=1;
```

The query I have so far allows me to see that I have the time entries connected properly to their matching projects, but that is all I have been able to figure out.  So in other words, this SQL statement does not exactly solve my problem.

Plus, even if it did work, I think the way I laid it out looks like 200 lbs of bird poop.  There must be a better/more optimized way to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I am relatively new and I have been pouring hours into solving this problem.

UPDATE:

Ok, here is the time_entries table:

```
+----+------------+---------+----------+-------+----------+-------------+------------+-------+--------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | project_id | user_id | issue_id | hours | comments | activity_id | spent_on   | tyear | tmonth | tweek | created_on          | updated_on          |
+----+------------+---------+----------+-------+----------+-------------+------------+-------+--------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |          1 |       1 |        1 |   .25 |  test    |          9  | 2015-11-04 | 2015  |    11  |  45   | 2015-11-04 08:18:12 | 2015-11-04 10:18:12 |
|  2 |          2 |       1 |        1 |   .25 |  test2   |          9  | 2015-11-04 | 2015  |    11  |  45   | 2015-11-04 09:18:12 | 2015-11-04 12:18:12 |
+----+------------+---------+----------+-------+----------+-------------+------------+-------+--------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

As opposed to the original table that I first posted, the expected output would show this:

```
+----+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+-------+
| id | customized_type | customized_id | custom_field_id | value |
+----+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+-------+
| 1  | Project         |             1 |               1 | 01    |
| 2  | TimeEntry       |             1 |               4 | 01    |
| 3  | Project         |             2 |               1 | 02    |
| 4  | TimeEntry       |             2 |               4 | 02    |
| 5  | Project         |             3 |               1 | 03    |
| 6  | TimeEntry       |             3 |               4 | 03    |
| 7  | Project         |             4 |               1 | 04    |
| 8  | TimeEntry       |             4 |               4 | 04    |
+----+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+-------+
```

Comment: Sorry I dont understand your question. Can you put an example? We need current data and expected output to see what is your need.

Comment: You have not shown the structure and content of the `time_entries` table in your question.